# ExtJS - Custom MessageBox icon appearing multiple times

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I have an `Extjs 4` app with a message box and a custom icon class to show a checkbox. No matter what 32x32 `*.png` I put there the picture repeats itself.

What's the proper way to format the icon so that it won't repeat?

[image: Evidence]

[image: Picture]

**Code**

```
 Ext.Msg.show({
     title: 'Success',
     msg: 'Control settings changed.',
     icon: 'save-success',
     buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
  });

//CSS
    .save-success{
         background-image: url(../images/icons/accept-1.png);
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `save-success`, add no repeat:

```
.save-success{
  background-image: url(../images/icons/accept-1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```